# How is code reading the multi-array to output such a format

Tags: python, list

```
groups = [["Roy","Sam","Amy"],["Tom","Jerry"]]
```

Trying to understand the output I am getting from this code

```
for group in groups: 
  for name in group: 
     print(group)

['Roy', 'Sam', 'Amy']
['Roy', 'Sam', 'Amy']
['Roy', 'Sam', 'Amy']
['Tom', 'Jerry']
['Tom', 'Jerry']
```

Comment: Try `print(name)` instead of `print(group)` - you're not printing what you _intended_ to print.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you meant to print `name` (the element in the inner-list), not `group` (the inner-list itself):

```
>>> groups = [["Roy","Sam","Amy"],["Tom","Jerry"]]
>>> for group in groups: 
...     for name in group:
...             print(name)
... 
Roy
Sam
Amy
Tom
Jerry
```